# Ajax request to checkout the login in database on the fly

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to understand how to make Ajax reuests, to check data that I put in form with data in database. So I have 3 files. First sing_up.html with my form:

```
    <html><head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.messageboxok{
    background-color: green;
    width: auto;
}

.messageboxerror{
    background-color: red;
    width: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main_block">

<h1>Registration</h1>
    <form id="registration" name="registration" action="registration.php" method="POST">
          <label for 'username'>Username: </label>
                <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName"/>
          <label for 'password'>Password: </label>
                <input type="password" name="pass"/>
          <label for 'first_name'>First name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="fullName"/>

          <label for 'email'>Email: </label>
                <input type="text" name="email"/>
          <br/>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          <span id="msgbox" style="display: none"></span>
     </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The next file registration.php where I connect to database and INSER values from my FORM:

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$pass = '8169x5it';
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=reg_form', $user, $pass );

if(isset($_POST['userName'])){
$form = $_POST;
//var_dump($_POST);
$userName = $form[ 'userName' ];
$pass = md5($form[ 'pass' ]);     // password_hash не работает
$fullName = $form[ 'fullName' ];
$email = $form[ 'email' ];



$sql = "INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers ( userName, pass, fullName, email ) VALUES 
                                                ( :userName, :pass, :fullName, :email )";

$query = $db->prepare( $sql );

if(
$query->execute( array( ':userName'=>$userName,
                        ':pass'=>$pass, 
                        ':fullName'=>$fullName,
                        ':email'=>$email ) ) ==true
//print_r($query);
){ 
    include 'all_users.php'; 

    }else{
    echo '0';
}
}
?>
```

And if the query execute i include file all_users.php where I SELECT data from database and put it in the tabe:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
    padding-left: 45px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$user = 'root';
$pass = '8169x5it';
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=reg_form', $user, $pass); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query -> execute();

$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //получить асоциативный масив
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
<?php


foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['userName'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['pass'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['fullName'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['email'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}


?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

So, I don't understand how to make ajax reuest, what URL I need to put in $.ajax registaration.php or all_users.php? Maybe you can give me some simple totorial about this question or it woud be better if you explain me how in work. I'll be grateful to you for your help!

Comment: There are lots of tutorials around for ajax. Look for one that includes php backend code. This is not a tutorial service. Short answer...put the php ajax processing code in a separate file

Comment: As I understand I need write url to file where I SELECT data from table?

Comment: Start with new php file...point ajax requests to that file url on server. This is not mandatory but is just to limit confusion while you get started

Comment: your file structure in question is not likely for Ajax, what ajax will do it post request to file and get response back while keep you on the main page without refreshing,